# Are there robust through-hole MOSFETs for beginners?

Tags: mosfet, esd, fet

I want to create switching circuits of less than 20mA in pos/neg 15V applications. 5 to 10 transistors, combination of N and P. Switching at 2.5kHz.

I simulated my circuits and now want to solder them on experiment boards. But afraid of all stories about damaging them in the process due to ESD and soldering heat. Since I am new, I will make the rookie mistakes, will have issues even finding the broken one(s), replace them and possibly damage other ones.

Is there a recommendation for a type number for a N and P type that might be “idiot proof”? I want to learn from the MOSFET’s functions more then from trying to protect them.

Thanks!

Comment: Chances are they are more robust than you think. And just get several of them and if you break one then use another. These are cheap parts we're talking about here.

Comment: honestly, unless you rub your bottom on the carpet all day long, there is pretty much no chance you'll damage anything (in theory, it can happen, but in practice it has never happened to me in years). But you never buy just one part anyway. If you buy mosfets to play around, it's unlikely you'll buy less than 5 of each kind (or better 10 if you can afford it). It's really not something to worry about, not at this stage.So find some with the specs you're okay with. Or. Even better.Ebay actually has sets of transistors for like 15$ with all kinds. Gets yourself a box of BJTs and a box of MOSFETs

Comment: "I simulated my circuits" implies that you now have sufficient knowledge to choose a part from : https://www.futurlec.com/TransMos.shtml

Comment: The key to fooling around with home-made circuits is called _current-limited bench voltage supply_. Always use one and limit the current to <100mA, then you are unlikely to fry something. Don't power things from batteries etc til you know the circuit is correct.

Comment: Regarding soldering heat, that's pretty much only a problem with LEDs and connectors. Most other part can take quite a beating when it comes to overheating.

Comment: Your question does not state it explicitly, but don't fool yourself into thinking though-hole = robust and SMD = weak.

Comment: Thanks all! I googled ESD and MOSFETs and got these horror stories. From all of you it is clear to me: it is no big issue. Ergo: I will just go for it (and yes, I have enough of them)

Comment: It all worked without issues!!

Comment: @Ilya I must object vigorously. ESD is a tricky menace. I have seen manifold damages to all sorts of devices (LEDs, PowerMOSFETs, logic). The damages typically aren't visible right after infliction, so hobbyists may live with a damaged device for years, while deterioration of parts in industrial production are caught by sheer mass, meticulous checks and long term usage. So don't soft-pedal ESD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MOSFETs proved all more robust than I had anticipated. I damaged none.

@Lundin's tip to use a current limited voltage supply has saved me a couple of time by now.